# How can you count the amount of 0's in each bootstrap in R?

Tags: r, loops, foreach

I am generating data using a two-part hurdle model via the Poisson distribution. Part of this model generates count data of solely of 0's and 1's. I am using the bootstrap method to generate enough observations to find error and power in my model to see if this model is appropriate

My question is simply "How do I count the amount of 0's in each iteration?". Occasionally, R will throw an error on one of the iterations which is along the lines of `Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit_zero$hessian)) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0`

This lead me to the conclusion that the matrix has either all 0's or all 1's.
My next step was to try to count the number of 0's in each iteration. However, I am not sure how to do this. The two problems I encountered were how to get each iteration if I am doing 1000 iterations with 1000 bootstraps, and how to actually count (and print) the amount of zeros within the loops. My attempt is below:

```
    errors <- 0
    no.zeros <- 0

    results <- foreach(iiii=icount(iterations), .combine = rbind) %do%{
      message("Parameter set: ",parameters.index, "/", nrow(kParameters$matrix), '\t', "Iteration: ", iiii, "/", iterations)
      data  = data.frame(gen.hurdle(n, a, b, b, c, c, i, i, i))
      data0 = data.frame(gen.hurdle(n, a, 0, 0, c, c, i, i, i))

      p_0     =1-mean(data$z_p)
      p_0_hat =1-mean(data$tstar)
      p_0_b0     =1-mean(data0$z_p)
      p_0_hat_b0 =1-mean(data0$tstar)

      #power

      fit1      = lm(m ~ x, data=data)
      fit2      = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=data, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial")

      a_hat     = summary(fit1)$coef[2,1]
      b1_hat    = summary(fit2)[[1]]$count[2,1]
      b2_hat    = summary(fit2)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
      ab1_hat   = prod(a_hat,b1_hat)
      ab2_hat   = prod(a_hat,b2_hat)

      #type I error

      fit3       = lm(m ~ x, data=data0)
      fit4       = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=data0, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial")

      a_hat_b0   = summary(fit3)$coef[2,1]
      b1_hat_b0  = summary(fit4)[[1]]$count[2,1]
      b2_hat_b0  = summary(fit4)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
      ab1_hat_b0 = prod(a_hat_b0,b1_hat_b0)
      ab2_hat_b0 = prod(a_hat_b0,b2_hat_b0)


      message(paste0("Bootstrapping..."))
      # bootstrap
      boot <- foreach(jjjj = icount(r), .combine = rbind, .errorhandling = "remove", .packages = c("pscl")) %dopar%{

        #power

        boot.data = data[sample(nrow(data), replace = TRUE), ]

        has.zero <- prod(boot.data$y) > 0
        if(!has.zero) {
          no.zeros <- no.zeros + 1
          boot.data$y[1] = 0
          warning(paste0("Iteration #",iiii, "  Bootstrap #",jjjj, " had no zeros!"), immediate. = TRUE, call. = FALSE)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `sum(boot.data$y==0)` should give you the number of zeros.  Or you could test whether `all(boot.data$y==0)` (for all-zero) or `any(boot.data$y!=0)` (for no-zero).

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly. A big problem I am having is that when printing, I am only printing numbers for the 54 changes in the initial indices over the big groups. Therefore, I am not getting 1000*1000 different lines telling me how many 0's. I suppose I need to fix how it is printing first.